# Dash says that its loading onto my local host but i get nothing when i go to the hosted page

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, plotly-dash

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash import dash_table
from dash import html
import dash_table.FormatTemplate as FormatTemplate

df = pd.read_csv('/content/SampleData.csv')
df.head()

pp = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
     html.H3("Example 1"),
     dash_table.DataTable(
         id="table",
         columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
         data=df.to_dict("records"),
         style_table={"height": "200px", "overflowY" : "auto"},
     )
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug= True, use_reloader=False, port = 8051)
```

I have tried using several different methods and no matter what i do it seems that it cannot load the local host. I am getting the "Dash is running on ...." but when i click the link it just says that the site cant be reached. I have tried disabling the debug as well as using different ports and disabling the reloader.

Any helpful comments would be appreciated. Could this just be related to me using google colab?

Comment: You cannot run a server in google colab or in a jupyter notebook for that matter. Dash is for running actual web application, it serves as the backend. If you are using google colab just use plotly for the visualization

Comment: If you install the following and keep plotly up-to-date, you can view Dash in the jupyter environment. `!pip install jupyter_dash;!pip install --upgrade plotly`

Comment: Dang, thats kinda what i figured. Thank you!